# Dealing with $(this) when there are multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now when there is effect like animate applied on multiple selector

```
$('.foo,.bar').animate({width: '250'}, 'slow',function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

**The console log return twice for `.foo` and `.bar`**

So how can I make other events based on this `.foo` only.

Something like this `$(this)+'.foo'` << <del>this is wrong</del>

I need to do other events based on the location of **(this)** `.foo`

Comment: You should use `.bar`, not `.goo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a separate selector for `$('.foo')`, or filter the existing selector down with `filter('.foo')`. These would be best, early on, to bind animation/events onto the correct set of elements.

Or check, in the animate callback, whether `$(this).is('.foo')` or `$(this).hasClass('foo')`. This approach would be best if your animation/events are already bound but you need to figure out what kind of DOM element they've been triggered on.

Generally binding things exactly like you want (the first approach) is best, but it depends what exactly you're trying to do.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/filter/
- http://api.jquery.com/is/
- http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 2):

Use `.filter()`

```
$(this).filter('.foo').dosomething()
```

If the `this` is a `.goo` element then `$(this).filter('.foo')` will not return anything, so the actions after that will not affect the `.goo` elements

Comment: The question now has `bar`. So its probably a good idea to edit your answer so it makes sense to future visitors. :)